# SSH - what is the meaning of permission denied(publickey, password)?

Tags: ssh, server, passwords

sorry if the question may be vague or not but I noticed that whenever I have tried to login to a ssh server it usually says "permission denied(publickey, password" or "permission denied(publickey, password,x, y)" where x and y are other strings but do these indicate what I could use to login to the server or are these the requirements needed to login to the server?

Answer (score 0):

It only lists the list of attempted authentication methods that failed at the initiation of the connection.

As described in [this article](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ssh-permission-denied-publickey) from [Marko Aleksic](https://rs.linkedin.com/in/marko-aleksi%C4%87-35752bb7?trk=public_profile_browsemap_profile-result-card_result-card_full-click)

> - One reason for the error may be sshd_config, the file that contains SSH server configuration.
> - The other possibility is that the authorized_keys file has insufficient permissions

if you have access to the server, stop the sshd service, and restart it manually in debug mode:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d
```

That way, you will see exactly what is attempted and *why* it fails.